# Incomplete schema in query result from Bigquery API

Tags: google-bigquery

When querying a Bigquery table (simple `SELECT * from [...]`) via the API using [Jobs.query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query) I get this returned as the schema:

```json
 "schema": {
  "fields": [
   {
    "name": "all",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "timestamp",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "last_timestamp",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "unique",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },...
```

But the actual schema (which is correctly returned by [Tables.get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/get)) is:

```json
 "schema": {
  "fields": [
   {
    "name": "all",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "description": "All searches"
   },
   {
    "name": "timestamp",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "description": "Time of processing"
   },
   {
    "name": "last_timestamp",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "description": "Last event"
   },
   {
    "name": "unique",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "description": "Unique users"
   },
```

I'm using the query results in an App Script that populates a spreadsheet and I'd like to use the description fields from the schema as column names. I could use `Table.get` to get the real schema but I'd like to understand why I'm getting an incomplete schema with the first query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jobs.query API gives you schema of result of your query (which is saved in temporary table in background). In this table  - there is no description for fields even though their types, mode, etc. are derived from schema of involved in query table(s)

Tables.get API from the other side - actually returns table's schema and that is why you see all about this table including descriptions.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense based on the response I get. But raises the question why does the example response in the docs for [Jobs.getQueryResults](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/getQueryResults#response) contain description fields in the schema?

Comment: i can be wrong - but i would say that documentation is not 100% perfect. in this particular case i think it is copy-paste issue for table resources section that is in use in many different APIs

Comment: Good catch. The documentation is auto-generated from our API definition, and the schema portion of the API definition is shared between the various places in the API where schemas appear. However, because the query engine does not generate a description for query result schemas, this field will be omitted for all query results (at least for the time being).